# how to extract markdown from yml with the original formatting

Tags: python, markdown, restructuredtext, pypandoc

i have some yml file, the remark entity contains markdown, how do I achieve successful data extraction from remark with the original string formatting.

Structure of yaml

test.yml

```
remark: "iljoijhoijhoiho pojpojpoij ohouihoui hp[oipoi
oiiohoihjoijh [p[pik[ [oi[p

kughkughiupokjpoj uiohgiuoh poipojk kpoip 

ouiyioyh[pop[uouypoipoikoiuo

"
```

my code

```
import yml
import pypandoc

content = yml.load('test.yml')

remark = content.get('remark', None)

text = pypandoc.convert_text(remark, 'rst', format='md')

print(text)
```

I expect a similar output as in the source file, but I get the wrong one

Output:

```
 iljoijhoijhoiho pojpojpoij ohouihoui hp[oipoi oiiohoihjoijh [p[pik[ [oi[p
kughkughiupokjpoj uiohgiuoh poipojk kpoip
ouiyioyh[pop[uouypoipoikoiuo
| heading 1 | heading 3 | heading 2 | |------------|------------|------------| | string 1,1 | string 1,3 | string 1,2 | | string 2,1 | string 2,3 | string 2,2 | | string 3,1 | string 3,3 | string 3,2 |
```

Comment: So the problem is that the newlines are not there anymore or that the markdown table should not be in the output?

Comment: Formulate your question differently please

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the output you are getting? Is the formatting wrong or the amount of text (or something else)?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't understand how to store multiline values in YAML

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was:
To write multiline values in YAML, you can use a special format called a "literal block". Literal blocks start with the | or > character and allow you to insert multi-line strings without having to escape special characters.About